# Populate with Mongoose return null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with mongoose and a referenced document. I see in the mongoose documentation the populate method, but it doesn't work well. this my code:

producto.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('Producto', {
    referencia: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    talla: Number,
    color:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Color'
    },
    foto: String,
    precioCosto: Number,
    precioVenta: Number,
    descripcion: String,
    tipoProducto:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'TipoProducto'
    },
    proveedor:{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Proveedor'
    }
});
```

color.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Color', {
    nombreColor: String,
    codigoColor: String
});
```

the query:

```
Producto.find().populate('color').exec(function(err, productos){
    console.log(productos);
    if (err){
        res.send(err);
    }

    res.json(productos);            
});
```

and in the result color is null:

```
[{
_id: "53618fd658dda21008000003"
color: null
descripcion: "11"
foto: "11"
precioCosto: 11
precioVenta: 11
proveedor: "53618f9fb3471b25ef46b504"
referencia: "11"
talla: 11
tipoProducto: "53618f15b3471b25ef46b503"
}]
```

thanks in advance

Comment: That means that there wasn't a color found with a matching `_id`.

Comment: Check your underlying collections. I would guess that when you created your `Color` object, you assigned it to `Producto` and saved that, however I am betting that you never saved the `Color` object itself, so it is not in the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I checked de `_id` and is the same. On the other hand don't quite understand how to solve the problem with your answer Neil.